# Kivy IDs needing a clock schedule

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to access the widgets in my .kv file from the python file and I have found this weird thing where if I access the IDs from the on_enter() or on_pre_enter() event from the screen, the .ids is empty and I can't access my widgets.
In order to access them, I have to create another method and Clock.schedule it. Can someone explain me why this happens...

Working method

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def add_labelinputs(self, dt):
        print(self.ids)
    
    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_labelinputs)
```

Not working method (empty dict)

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):
        print(self.ids)
```

Kivy file

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

WindowManager:
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'MainScreen'

    GridLayout:
        id: mainLayout
        cols: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Kivy that has been around for a long time. It only affects the first `Screen` added to a `ScreenManager` in `kv`. A workaround is to not use `kv` for building the `ScreenManager`. Try modifying your kv to:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'MainScreen'

    GridLayout:
        id: mainLayout
        cols: 1
```

And modifying your `build()` method to:

```
def build(self):
    Builder.load_string(kv)  # assumes kv string is defined as above
    sm = WindowManager()
    sm.add_widget(MainScreen())
    return sm
```